# Hide HTTPS warning when trying to download files over HTTP with Edge

Tags: c#, api, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

```
public class FilesController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Files/DownloadFile/{ProductID}/{FileName}/{UserID}")]
    public FileResult DownloadFile(int ProductID, string FileName, int UserID)
    {
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    }
}
```

Hi Everyone, I'm using API to download files.In my blazor server app (client) , when the user tries to download any file such as .xlsx or .ppt files  , it works in Chrome and Firefox , but in case of Microsoft Edge, it gives me "pptx file can't be downloaded securely".

My question , there are any configurations that I can add in the app.settings or web.config to bypass the SSL/TLS problem?

Open to Check the Error Message:

[image: Open to Check the Error Message]

Comment: Why is this an SSL/TLS problem?  Can you post the exact error message(s) ?

Comment: I'll try to add image. I'm trying to download a file by using API , but API is using Http instead of HTTPS.For this reason , in Microsoft Edge , when I try to click on a link to download a ".pptx" file , it gives me "pptx file can't be downloaded securely".

Comment: _"API is using Http instead of HTTPS"_ - why?

Comment: Use HTTPS then. Otherwise anything you do is unsafe. The error is quite accurate. I'm pretty sure Chrome and Firefox aren't happy either, and either you didn't notice the warnings or you use such outdated versions cut off from the internet that they don't complain. Or someone disabled the warnings. Don't do that

Comment: In fact, Chrome and Firefox started throwing big red content-obscuring warnings about HTTP sites *years* ago. The web admins and owners that claimed they didn't need HTTPS complained for a while but soon realized they had two options - fix their insecure sites or lose all traffic.

Comment: I've added an image for the error. I'll use Https instead of Http , but my web application is for test purpose now. When the client approve it , I'll use the SSL/TLS.

Comment: Assume they already approved it and use HTTPS. If you get a warning about the self-signed development certificate, trust it on the test machine and client. That's what it's for. In fact, there are a lot of actual duplicates that ask how to trust the development certificate rather than disabling it. You had to do extra work to use HTTP instead of HTTPS after all.

Comment: If you want to find out how to download files with Blazor there are some duplicate questions and an MS Docs article. You can use an `a` tag with the `download` attribute or create a data link with the file contents in Javascript. I [wrote one of these duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/124241141?noredirect=1) that shows both ways

Comment: Another reason to use HTTPS is that you get HTTP/2 and *far* faster performance this way, as the browser can download the myriad images, stylesheets and scripts Blazor uses in parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use SSL/TLS to secure the communications between the API and blazor server app (client-side). In other words,convert HTTP (port 80) to HTTPS (port 443).